# OpenModelica on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, modelica, openmodelica

Has anyone already installed OpenModelica on Ubuntu 19.10?
It seems that the repository link does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your could try to replace `´lsb_release -cs´` by `xenial` (Ubuntu 18.04) and try if it works under Ubuntu 19.10. So try one of the three:

```
for deb in deb deb-src; do echo "$deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt xenial nightly"; done | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list
for deb in deb deb-src; do echo "$deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt xenial stable"; done | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list
for deb in deb deb-src; do echo "$deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt xenial release"; done | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list
```

Answer (score 1):

From the OpenModelica [installation instructions](https://openmodelica.org/download/download-linux) you can see that [apt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software))-based distros will download packages from here:
http://build.openmodelica.org/apt/dists/

Ubuntu releases get names in alphabetical order, 19.10 starts with E (Eoan Ermine).
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Knowing this you can see that there are no packages for Ubuntu 19.10 yet. But I assume there will be in the near future.